# How to make Images auto resize to fit in a line with margin between?

Tags: html, css

So I'm learning html and CSS and trying to make images fit in a line. It seems that the below code isn't working:

```
.container .portfolio-region ul li:nth-child(2){
        margin: 0 30px;
    }
```

If I increase the margin to `100px`, It will work but then It won't fit in a line.
I can see in the example that the images auto resize to fit the `margin`. I've included pics in the below. Can someone help me with this? Thank you very much.

code:

```css
/*================== TABLE OF CONTENT =================*/


/*
     1. RESET CSS 
     2. DEFAULT STYLE 
     3. STYLE PORTFOLIO
    */


/*===============  1. RESET CSS ==============*/

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}


/*===============  2. DEFAULT STYLE ==============*/

.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  padding: 0 12px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}


/*===============  3. STYLE PORTFOLIO ==============*/

.container .heading {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px 0;
}

.container .heading .heading-title {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.container .heading .heading-description {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: italic;
  color: gray;
}

.container .portfolio-region {
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.container .portfolio-region .portfolio-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
}

.container .portfolio-region ul {
  text-align: center;
}

.container .portfolio-region ul li:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0 30px;
}

.container .portfolio-region .portfolio-item .img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.container .portfolio-region .portfolio-item h4 {
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.container .portfolio-region .portfolio-item p {
  color: #6C757F;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Assignment 1 - 04.03.2020</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="portfolio-section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="heading">
        <h2 class="heading-title">PORTFOLIO</h2>
        <h3 class="heading-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio-region">
        <ul>
          <li class="portfolio-item">
            <img src="assets/image/01-thumbnail.jpg">
            <h4> Threads</h4>
            <p>Illustration</p>
          </li>
          <li class="portfolio-item">
            <img src="assets/image/02-thumbnail.jpg">
            <h4>Explore</h4>
            <p>Graphic design</p>
          </li>
          <li class="portfolio-item">
            <img src="assets/image/03-thumbnail.jpg">
            <h4>Finish</h4>
            <p>Identity</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: Example]

[image: My result]

Comment: here is two images which one is your output and an expected output

Comment: The first one is the expected output sir. I want to make spaces between my images but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there could be many ways to achieve that first is to apply the [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin) like

```
margin-top: ;
margin-bottom: ;
margin-left: ;
margin-right: ;
```

or in one line like

```
margin: w x y z;
```

where `w` is for `top`, `x` is for `right`, `y` is for `bottom` and `z` is for `left`
or you can use [`flex-box`](https://www.slideshare.net/ScrumBreakfastVietnam/dn-scrumbreakfast-css-flexbox-and-grid-the-future-of-website-layouts-july-28-2018) where you have to apply `justify-content: space-around;` on the container of all image like the following

```
.container{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the height in CSS to number of pixels you want. For example

```
height: 100px;
```

After this, all pictures with this class would have the same height.